# Tkinter - Accessing class value of checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get a working example going of retrieving the text within a gui when a button is clicked in a tkinter GUI. I am using Python 36.

How do I access the guiCheckState variable from within the button?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.printButton = Button(master, text="PRINT VALUE", width=17, command=Main.printButton, background='GREEN').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

        guiCheckState = IntVar(master)
        self.testCheck = Checkbutton(master, text="Max Price: ", variable=guiCheckState, background='#b3d0e8').grid(row=13,column=0,sticky="w")

class Main():
    def main():
        root = Tk() 
        root.geometry('300x300')
        root.configure(background='#b3d0e8')
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)
        gui = MyGUI(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def printButton():
        print(MyGUI.guiCheckState) #AttributeError: type object 'MyGUI' has no attribute 'guiCheckState'

Main.main()
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: There is no variable to access; you stored it only in a local Python variable, so it was garbage-collected as soon as `MyGUI.__init__()` finished.  (Passing a Tkinter var to a widget does not store a reference to it, just its name, so this behaves rather differently than anything written in pure Python.)

Comment: I understand that the error means that the attribute isn't found. I'm still pretty new to Python, having come from C#. In C# we don't have this total insanity because we don't have to write "self" all over everything, which is apparently part of the problem here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access `guiCheckState`, you must do a couple of things. First, it must be an instance variable. As written, it's just a local variable. In python, to make a variable an instance variable you need to prefix it with `self.`:

```
self.guiCheckState = IntVar(master)
```

With that, if you have a reference to an instance of `MyGUI` then you can reference the variable via the instance:

```
gui = MyGUI()
gui.guiCheckState
```

However, `guiCheckState` is an object, so if you want the value of that object you need to call its `get` method:

```
print(gui.guiCheckState.get())
```

In your example you're calling `main()` incorrectly, plus you've set `gui` in that function as a local variable. Again, to be able to reference it outside of the function where it's defined, you need to set it as an instance variable:

```
self.gui = MyGUI(root)
```

For that to work, `main` needs to be an instance method. In python, that means it has to accept `self` as it's first parameter (it doesn't literally *have* to be named `self`, but that's a convention that no python program violates). The same is also true for the `printButton` function.

Finally, you are referencing `printButton` incorrectly in the button. You need an instance of `Main` rather than the class `Main` (eg: `the_main_instance.printButton` rather than `Main.printButton`). You can have class functions in python by adding some syntactic sugar, but in your example it's probably better to keep them as instance functions.

The solution to that is a bit tricky since the instance of `MyGUI` doesn't have a reference to the instance of `Main`. So, we have to pass it to `MyGUI` if you want the instance of `MyGUI` to be able to reference it.

One last bit of advice: in python, when you do `foo().bar()`, the result is the value of `bar()`. Thus, when you do something like `Button(...).grid(...)`, the result is the result of `grid(...)`. In tkinter, `.grid(...)` returns `None`. The best practice is to always call `grid` (or `pack` or `place`) on a separate line so that your variables don't get set to `None`. Plus, experience has taught me that grouping your layout statements together makes the code much easier to understand.

Ok, one *more* bit of advice. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (the python style guide) discourages wildcard imports, for some very good reasons. Unfortunately, a lot of tkinter tutorials use wildcard imports. Many people consider this to be a bad practice. Since you're just starting out, I recommend you stick to PEP8.

Wrap all of that together, and your code would look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI():
    def __init__(self, master, main):
        self.master = master
        self.main = main

        self.printButton = tk.Button(master, text="PRINT VALUE", width=17,
                                     command=self.main.printButton,
                                     background='GREEN')

        self.guiCheckState = tk.IntVar(master)
        self.testCheck = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Max Price: ",
                                        variable=self.guiCheckState,
                                        background='#b3d0e8')

        self.printButton.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w")
        self.testCheck.grid(row=13,column=0,sticky="w")

class Main():
    def main(self):
        root = tk.Tk() 
        root.geometry('300x300')
        root.configure(background='#b3d0e8')
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)
        self.gui = MyGUI(root, self)
        root.mainloop()

    def printButton(self):
        print(self.gui.guiCheckState.get())

main = Main()
main.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with TKinter, but it looks like it should be `self.guiCheckState` and `self.gui`, and you should reference it with `self.gui.guiCheckState`.

I.e `guiCheckState` should be a field of an *instance* of MyGui, and `gui` should be a field of `Main`.

Comment: Any chance that you can show a working example using the above? I'm trying the things that you referenced and I can't figure it out.

Comment: I understand that the error means that the attribute isn't found. I'm still pretty new to Python, having come from C#. In C# we don't have this total insanity because we don't have to write "self" all over everything, which is apparently part of the problem here.

Comment: @RandallFeuerlein: I don't think JoshuaF is condescending. You seem to lack a basic understanding of how python classes work. They were just trying to help by giving you a link to relevant documentation. Don't take things so personally. Most people who write answers and give comments are doing it in the spirit of trying to help.